# How to define spaces in Urdu (Jameel Noori Nastaleeq) font in android?

Tags: android, fonts, font-face

I want to define like that [image], used Urdu (Jameel Noori Nastaleeq) font, string define like that `<string name="spaces">خوش           آمدید</string>` in TextView,

```
ttf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/Jameel Noori Nastaleeq.ttf");

tvRandomLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRandomLabel);
    tvRandomLabel.setTypeface(ttf);
```

But after the build application not show the spaces, [image]

Comment: put khush amdeed inside double quotes!

Comment: i don't know answer. just want to say font name is great :P

Comment: @Muhammad Babar it is define already in string <string name="spaces">خوش آمدید</string>

Comment: @EngrWaseemArain do it like that "خوش آمدید"

Comment: @Muhammad Babar i have also try that

Comment: &#160; use it inplace of space

Comment: @Muhammad Babar#160 is unicode ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this unicode "No-BREAK_SPACE":

```
ttf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/Jameel Noori Nastaleeq.ttf");

tvRandomLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRandomLabel);
    tvRandomLabel.setTypeface(ttf);
    // use this unicode for single space \u00A0
    tvRandomLabel.setText(yourtext+"\u00A0"+your text);
```

more unicodes [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm).